# Should the new MFC Feature pack contols appear in VS toolbox

Tags: visual-studio, mfc-feature-pack

I'm trying to use some of the new MFC feature pack controls on an existing MFC app, with VS2008 SP1.  None of the new controls appear in the dialog-editor toolbox.

Should I expect them to be there, and if so, do people have any suggestion for how to get them to appear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there no IDE support for new "NextMFC" controls. There also no plans to add it to VS2008 at this moment, we need to wait for VS2010!